# how to deauth clients in a "secured wireless network"

Tags: kali-linux, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

I am using `aireplay-ng -0 0 -a *bssid* -c *clientMac* wlan0`  command which works fine in my home or school network.

I was in a club yesterday that has something such special in their bssid that I am not able to deauth anyone connected to that network.

I tried with my own computer, aireplay is not working it sends deauth packges I see in cmd but connection not drop at all.

What the heck might be about that access-point? how can I force deauth all client in this network?

Edited: I share modem device info if its necessary;

```
MAC Address/OUI    Vendor {Company}
50:65:F3           Hewlett Packard
```

Comment: basicly you can use the mdk3 tool ! you can read more here https://tools.kali.org/wireless-attacks/mdk3 add the d option

Comment: modem is shorthand for "modulator-demodulator". It sounds like you are talking about a WiFi access point or a "WAP". The WAP might also be a modem but that is not relevant to the discussion. Use WAP to talk about the wifi part and "modem" to talk about the connection out to the ISP.

Comment: @00HassenCDX7 I will check it and post results here

Comment: @HackSlash yeah you right, post edited but what about answer regarding to the question :)

Comment: Not every device\firmware revision is going to have the same vulnerabilities. If the device you are attacking is not vulnerable to the attack you are using then you need to develop a new attack. You either have to figure out how they are mitigating the vulnerability and modify the exploit or find a new vulnerability.

Comment: @00HassenCDX7 nothing fancy about mdk3 tool it use same way for deauth with aireplay-ng, and it doesnt work..